# Angular - copy factory variable into private variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular service. Here is my service :

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Daytime',function () {
    var factory = {};
    var _data = {};
    factory.defaultCalendar = {
        'kerry': {
            first: '7,16',
            second: '16.05,24',
            firstStart: 7,
            firstEnd: 16,
            secondStart: 16.05,
            secondEnd: 24
        },
        'william' : {
            first: '7,16',
            second: '16.05,24',
            firstStart: 7,
            firstEnd: 16,
            secondStart: 16.05,
            secondEnd: 24
         }

    };

});
```

I want to copy *factory.defaultCalendar* to *_data* . I used two method :

```
_data = angular.copy(this.defaultCalendar);
```

And

```
_data = this.defaultCalendar;
```

Although after both of them , I get _data as undefined .

how to copy  `factory.defaultCalendar` into another variable in my factory?

Comment: In that function you need to return `factory` otherwise the service is just undefined?

Comment: `_data  = factory.defaultCalendar` should work

Comment: I have tested here : http://jsfiddle.net/k3phygpz/965/

Answer (score 1):

With     `factory.defaultCalendar = {`

you are creating an object `default` into a *variable* called `factory`.

So, using `_data = angular.copy(this.defaultCalendar);` won't simply work, because your `defaultCalendar` object it's inside the *variable* `factory` , that is **completely different** from the `this.` reference.

### The solution

change your `_data = angular.copy(this.defaultCalendar);`

to

`_data = angular.copy(factory.defaultCalendar);`

after the defaultCalendar initialization.

The entire code can be changed to:

```
app.factory('Daytime',function () {
   var factory = {};
   factory.defaultCalendar = {
       'kerry': {
        first: '7,16',
        second: '16.05,24',
        firstStart: 7,
        firstEnd: 16,
        secondStart: 16.05,
        secondEnd: 24
    },
    'william' : {
        first: '7,16',
        second: '16.05,24',
        firstStart: 7,
        firstEnd: 16,
        secondStart: 16.05,
        secondEnd: 24
     }
   };
   var _data = angular.copy(factory.defaultCalendar); //changed position, and 'this' to 'factory'
});
```

Comment: where I can use this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this refrence in the factory, you should directly write 
      `_data = factory.defaultCalendar;`

You can refer to the documentaion of different angular providers [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `factory` variable inside the factory.